# How to insert into oracle table with a condition statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am required to calculate the electricity bill,

1. $0.20 for the first KW
2. $0.30 for the 2nd KW
3. $1 for the subsequent KW

i have the tables set up for this.

```
INSERT INTO ELECTRIC_BILL(ADDRESS_ID, READING_ID, BILLING_DATE, DUE_DATE, BILL_AMOUNT)
SELECT 41, 63, TO_DATE('10-SEPTEMBER-2020','DD-MON-YYYY'),
       TO_DATE('10-OCTOBER-2020','DD-MON-YYYY'),
       <<HOW TO ADD IF ELSE STATEMENT HERE? >>
FROM READER;
```

I think i need some improvement on my mathematic as i cant seem to find a solution without needing if else statement.

thank you all for your help!

Comment: what is the schema of your table `READER` ?
Is the usage amount a decimal/double type in nature ?

Comment: Please share some sample data and desired output

Comment: @SupunDeSilva it is double type. in READER there are 2 attribute, CUR_READING and PREV_READING

Comment: @Tejash example, IF (CUR_READING - PREV_READING) > 1000 THEN ..... ELSE ....

Comment: The equation i came up with, if (CUR_READING - PREV_READING) > 2000 THEN 0.2 + 0.30 + (1 * ((CUR_READING - PREV_READING) - 2000))

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CASE..WHEN` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO ELECTRIC_BILL (
    ADDRESS_ID,
    READING_ID,
    BILLING_DATE,
    DUE_DATE,
    BILL_AMOUNT
)
    SELECT 41,
           63,
           TO_DATE('10-SEPTEMBER-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),
           TO_DATE('10-OCTOBER-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),
           CASE
               WHEN CUR_READING - PREV_READING > 2000 THEN
                   0.2 + 0.3 + ( 1 * ( ( CUR_READING - PREV_READING ) - 2000 ) )  -- FOR MORE THAN 2 KW
               WHEN CUR_READING - PREV_READING > 1000 THEN
                   ( ( CUR_READING - PREV_READING ) - 1000 ) * 0.3 + 0.2 -- FOR KW BETWEEN 1 AND 2
               ELSE
                   ( CUR_READING - PREV_READING ) * 0.2 -- FOR KW LESS THAN 1
           END AS BILL_AMOUNT
      FROM READER;
```

Comment: Updated the answer according to your exact column names

Comment: I keep getting missing keyword error from this..

Comment: You can check now, I have replaced `YOUR_READING_COLUMN` from the second WHEN clause with `CUR_READING - PREV_READING`

Comment: Changed that but i have a unique constraint violated error. i have tested with VALUES instead of SELECT and it works. and my schema does not have a unique constraint for these values..

Comment: i am using GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY for my primary key

Comment: You need to check the unique constraints of the table `ELECTRIC_BILL`